# how to use the handle structure inside a non-callback function in matlab gui programming

Tags: matlab, user-interface, handle

When I try to access the data member of the handle structure inside a non-callback function, it gives me "Reference to non-existent field ..." error. Or is it the situation that you can ONLY use the handle structure inside a callback function in matlab gui programming?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use handles inside a random function you have to use the following:

```
handles = guidata(hObject);
```

This allows you to "load" the handle structure and where `hOject` is a handle, be sure to pass this variable in the function you are writing with an argument:

```
function [var_out] = my_function(var_in,hObject,handles)
    handles=guidata(hObject);
    %some code
    guidata(hObject,handles);
end;
```

The last line is useful if you want to "save" everything you've done with the handle structure.
This way, you'll be able to use the handle structure in a non-callback function:

```
function my_callback(hObject,eventdata,handles)
    %some code
    [var_out] = my_function(var_in,hObject,handles);
end
```

All this works if you call `my_function` in a callback.